# How can i set all 'id' columns in my database in all table to autoincrement?

Tags: mysql

How can i set all 'id' columns in my database in all table to autoincrement in one query?

is there a query that i can use?

Comment: Why not TRUNCATE?

Comment: @P.Salmon how can i truncate that many tables?

Comment: Read the table names from information_schema.tables. loop through them create sql statements for submission to dynamic sql - and I'm pretty sure if you search you will find.

Comment: I've read it, i donn't really understand it.

Comment: @P.Salmon *Why not TRUNCATE?* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e484c6446805de8d2534b1682d12037

Comment: Okay... i will try that... also is there a way to make all id column in the database to be auto incremeted